# CoffeeScript + KnockoutJS Function Binding

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, knockout.js

I'm using CoffeeScript and KnockoutJS and have a problem getting the values of my view model from within a function.

I have a view model:

```
window.Application || = {}
class Application.ViewModel 
    thisRef = this
    searchTerm: ko.observable("")
    search: ->
        alert @searchTerm
```

Which compiles to:

```
window.Application || (window.Application = {});
Application.ViewModel = (function() {
  var thisRef;
  function ViewModel() {}
  thisRef = ViewModel;
  ViewModel.prototype.searchTerm = ko.observable("");
  ViewModel.prototype.search = function() {
    return alert(this.searchTerm);
  };
  return ViewModel;
})();
```

This view model is part of a parent view model which exposes it as field. The problem is that I can't get a reference to the child view model. In the search function 'this' is a instance of the parent, which I don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the `search` function 'this' is a instance of the parent...

That depends on how you call it. If you do

```
m = new Application.ViewModel
m.search()
```

then `this` will be `m`; if you write

```
obj = {search: m.search}
obj.search()
```

then `this` will be `obj`.

Anyway, just use CoffeeScript's `=>` operator:

```
search: =>
    alert @searchTerm
```

That way, `this`/`@` within `search` will point to the `ViewModel` instance.

`thisRef` will, as Travis says, just point to the class, not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `thisRef` object hanging around, use `thisRef.searchTerm` instead of `@searchTerm`. I often have that happen when using jQuery...

```
doSomething = ->
  target = $(@)
  $("#blah").click ->
    target.doSomethingElse()
```

Since `@doSomethingElse()` would be bound to the DOM element the click was executed for. Not what I want.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry I should have taken the thisRef out of my code example. It doesn't help me much anyway